# Unity 2018.2.6f1 + GoogleVR 1.170.0 - crash while switching to Android platform or building apk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

please need help, i have a simple VR app and i use only a GVR Reticle pointer for select the buttons

To reproduce create a new empty Unity 2018.2.6f1 project, then there are 2 cases:

- When i'm already switched to android platform Unity will crash while importing the GoogleVR package
- In standalone platform package will be imported successfully, but it will crash douring the android apk building or while switching to android platform

Comment: Are you getting any error messages while doing this? If so please post the error message.

Comment: There is no messages just bug report window appears after crash, but in the log i have found these lines that seems to be relevant: ntdll.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module ntdll.dll at 0033:348582cd.

Write to location 0000000000000008 caused an access violation.

Comment: @remy_rm I have same issue. it just crash Unity and prompt send report option

Comment: @AmirJaouani did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm back to version 2018.1.0f2 of unity, and it worked

Comment: thanks for reply @AmirJaouani